# Remove tr - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove a TR in a table view. when I hit delete.

However I am having issue doing this.

```
$("#deletelead").live('click', function(event){
    deleteid = $("tbody td.small input:checkbox:checked").map(function(i, el) { return $(el).attr("id"); }).get();
    $("tr").remove().before("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(i, el) { return $(el).attr("id"); }).get();
    //alert(deleteid.length);   

    $.each(deleteid, function(index, value) { 




    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "system/classes/core.php",
                data: "task=deletelead&customerid="+deleteid,
                success: function(data){
                    if((data) == 1)
                    {
                        //loadadminlayout();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    alert(data);    
                    }
                }
            });
    return false;

    });
});
```

jQuery code that creates the table

```
function listallleads(){


    var script = document.createElement('link');
    script.href = 'theme/style/manageleads.css';
    script.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    script.type = 'text/css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8) {
        var script = document.createElement('link');
        script.href = 'theme/style/ie-manageleads.css';
        script.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        script.type = 'text/css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }



    $.getJSON(URLLINK, function(dataleads) {

      $.each(dataleads,function(i, myleads){
        var businessname = "";
        if(myleads.Company == null || myleads.Company == "null" || myleads.Company == "")
        {
        businessname = myleads.TradingName; 
        }
        else
        {
        businessname = myleads.Company;
        }

        if(usertype == 3)
        {
            if(myleads.AMStatus == 1)
            {
            leadstatus = "All Confirmed";   
            }
            else 
            {
            leadstatus = "Not Confirmed";   
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            leadstatus = leadstatusselect(myleads.LeadStatus);
        }

        if(myleads.AMStatus == 1)
        {
            myleads.AMStatus = "one";
        }



        cssstats = "lead"+myleads.AMStatus



            $("tbody").append('<tr id="'+myleads.customer_id+' class="'+cssstats+'">'+
'           <td id="row" class="small"><input id="'+myleads.customer_id+'" type="checkbox"></td>'+
'           <td>'+myleads.CreatedTime+'</td>'+
'           <td>'+businessname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center">'+myleads.FirstName+' '+myleads.LastName+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center">'+myleads.Phone+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center bigger">'+myleads.Email+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center">'+myleads.stafffirstname+' '+myleads.stafflastname+'</td>'+
'           <td class="center last">'+leadstatus+'</td>'+
'       </tr>');
      });
        qs.cache();
    });

    if(usertype == 3)
    {
    leadtype = "A/M Status";    
    }
    else
    {
    leadtype = "Lead Status";   
    }

    $("#todo_bg").hide();
    $("#menuarea").html('<a id="gotohome"><div id="backmain" class="backbg">Back</div></a><div id="nav" class="backbgright">Manage Business Lead</div>'+
                        '<div id="dowithleads"><button id="editlisting" class="blackbutton manage">Edit Listing</button><button id="sendemailout" class="blackbutton manage">Send Message</button> <button id="deletelead" class="blackbutton manage">Delete Lead</button>'+
                        '<div id="searchbox"><form action="#"><fieldset><input type="text" name="search" value="" id="searchleads" placeholder="Search" autofocus /></fieldset></form></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div id="dowithleads"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="sortable paginated scrollTable" id="manageleads">'+
'   <thead class="fixedHeader">'+
'       <tr>'+
'           <th class="small" id="first"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkall" value="Yes"></th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Created Time</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Company</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Lead Name</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Phone No.</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha bigger">Email</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha">Lead Owner</th>'+
'           <th class="sort-alpha last">'+leadtype+'</th>'+
'       </tr>'+
'   </thead>'+
'   <tbody class="scrollContent"></tbody>'+
'</table></div>');  


    setTimeout(function(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'js/table.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
    stripedTable();
    },2000);


    var qs = $('input#searchleads').quicksearch('table#manageleads tbody tr');
}
```

Comment: I would like to know that why are you using `before` & `get` & `map`. They serve different purpose then I can check in your code..

Comment: Also what is the html code because your current js will remove all the `tr` in the html document. And here based on what condition you want to delete the `tr` is not clear and also what error you are getting pls tell us so that it will be clear to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, the HTML is jQuery code I'll post it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('tbody tr').each(function(){
                if ($(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
                     $(this).remove();
                }
          });
```